# How to Prevent JEditable Form Submission with Webkit browsers

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, form-submit, jeditable

Using the JEditable JQuery plugin, and everything seemed to work fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome whenever I selected something out of a JEditable dropdown, or clicked Enter when editing a JEditable textbox, the form JEditable creates on the fly was being submitted, and my entire page was refreshing. I didn't want that to happen, as I've got it configured to call a custom function that makes an Ajax call to do the update. How do you keep the JEditable form from being submitted when changing the value of one of the form inputs?

My understanding from researching online is this is a Webkit-browser issue, not just a Chrome issue, as it seems Webkit-based browsers automatically submit forms when inputs in the form are changed.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial-and-error I found one way to get around this is to use JEditable's bind function. The bind function gives you access to the form JEditable creates, and you can hijack the onsubmit event with that.

So first, create a function to override the form's onsubmit event.

```
var bindSubmitDisableWebkitSubmission = function(settings, self){

        $('form', self).attr("onsubmit", "return false;");
    }
```

Then bind that function to the various JEditable events that you don't want to submit the form.

```
$.editable.types['select'].plugin = bindSubmitDisableWebkitSubmission;
```

Note that using preventDefault and returning false (see below) didn't work.

```
function bindSubmitDisableWebkitSubmission (settings, self) {
         $('form', self).submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
```